# What does the following Chmod command do?

Tags: macos, terminal, command, chmod

I encountered a command on the following page. http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/07/setting-up-google-code-with-git.html

chmod go= .netrc

Can't find it in the chmod man.

Comment: If you're using GNU chmod (e.g, on linux), the Description section of the manpage has a very clear and concise description symbolic modes are used, and the info manual has exactly the same example you gave. If you're using BSD chmod (e.g., on Mac), the Examples of Valid Modes section of the manpage has exactly the same example you gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chmod go= .netrc` No access to group and others to file `.netrc`.
`chmod go=rx .netrc` Giving read and execute access`

Basically you can add `+`, subtract `-` and assign `=` certain access levels.

Check [this link](http://catcode.com/teachmod/shortcuts.html)

Answer (score 2):

From "Examples of valid modes" in the chmod manpage:

> go=           clear all mode bits for group and others.

Comment: This section of the manpage doesn't exist in the GNU version—but there's a very clear explanation right at the top of the manpage, and the example _does_ exist in the info manual. So, this is a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

This means "set these permissions absolutely".  In this case, you'll be clearing the `g` and the `o` permissions on the file `.netrc` (since you didn't name any permissions after the equal sign).

If you did something like:

> chmod go=r .netrc

You'd be giving `read` permission to the `group` and `other`, but clearing all other permissions for `g` and `o`.

Here's some examples:

```
~> pico test.txt <-- Create a file with default permissions
~> ls -l test.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 mike  staff  7 Sep 12 09:39 test.txt
~> chmod go= test.txt <-- Clear the permissions on g and o
~> ls -l test.txt
-rw-------  1 mike  staff  7 Sep 12 09:39 test.txt
~> chmod go=r test.txt <-- Set only read on g and o
~> ls -l test.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 mike  staff  7 Sep 12 09:39 test.txt
~> chmod o=rw test.txt <-- Set read and write only on o
~> ls -l test.txt
-rw-r--rw-  1 mike  staff  7 Sep 12 09:39 test.txt
```

See the [man](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2239/chmod-1/index.html) page under Symbolic Mode for more information.